# way to install iPhone App via browser?

Tags: ios, jailbreak

Hello I've created an app and I'm looking for a way to install the application with the help of LINK ... everyone be able to use it
Thanks in advance

Comment: Join enterprise developer program and you will be able to distribute your app through browser link to anyone. Of course that's against the rules of the program but it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can upload your app on [diawi](https://www.diawi.com/) , This site used to generate a link through which your app can be installed by anyone.

Comment: An error occurred:
4001009: Invalid .ipa file: missing embedded mobileprovision

Comment: So, you didn't include the provisioning profile in your project?